# Getting 404 not found when calling Asp.Net Core MVC action from Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to call index (with Post decorated) in Home controller and post below data (in json format), but its giving me 404 not found.

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginModel model)
{
    //login check code
}
```

client.js

```
loginUser: function (url, object) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(object);
        $.post(url, data, function (res) {
            if (!res.Message) {
                window.location.href = "/Dashboard/Dashboard";
            }
        });
    }

$('#login_id').click(function(){
    var loginModel=new Object();
    loginModel.Username= "username";
    loginModel.Password = "password";

    loginUser("Home/Index", loginModel)
});
```

In above JS code, there is no hit to Index action when $.Post gets execute. Tried with Postman as well as ARC client both.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: trye this `var loginUser = function (url, object) {`

Comment: loginUser function getting call. There is no problem with calling. $.Post unable to call Home/Index action of MVC.

Comment: I simulated your code, it's working for me. So Can you tell me what is showing developer console Network tab?

Comment: It's sending the request in correct way with proper Content-type, so there is not issue with jquery or your lib files. Is your controller action method are correct?

Comment: Controller Action method is same as I mentioned above. As you can see that on GET request, Index (HttpGet decorated) action getting call and login window coming, but HttpPost decorated Index action method has issue only. Please do let me know if you need anything else apart mentioned above.

Comment: This is most probably the issue with relative URL that you are passing to the method. Could you please try `loginUser("@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")", loginModel)`

Comment: @Rahul, Do you have [Authorize] on top of your controller?

Comment: @Rahul, I simulated your scenario in my local ans shared the project here https://github.com/rajdeepdebnath/aspnet-core-jquery-post

You can compare and let me know what is missing.

Comment: Hi @RajdeepDebnath. in local it works fine. When I publish it on server, i throws /Home/Login 404 not found. You can check this with same URL i mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, so it seems you are missing website name, you can try the 2nd answer by Okasha Momin; if it works, it's better than mine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#login_id').click(function(){
    var loginModel=new Object();
    loginModel.Username= "username";
    loginModel.Password = "password";

    loginUser("Home/Index", loginModel)
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rajdeep, I didn't downvote you. Sorry, i am not sure who did it.

Comment: Thank you Rajdeep. Yes, this was an URL issue you mentioned above.

Comment: What would happen if the website alias change or let's say I want to deploy it on something like `www.mywebsite.com` without any alias?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, then you need to specify accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

just change this line

> loginUser("Home/Index", loginModel)
> to this
> loginUser("/Home/Index", loginModel)